# drawing the mean in a pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots, statistics, awk

I would like to add a straight line to a pgfplot that indicates the mean of the data. For a histogram, this should be a vertical line; for a simple plot, a horizontal line. Now, I do get as far as in the provided minimal working example.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
1.84919
0.97280
4.78586
3.95797
4.50753
2.52274
5.13984
0.29474
5.39946
4.40204
\end{filecontents}
\newcommand*{\manmean}{3.3832}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[hist={bins=6,}, fill=teal, draw=teal!50!black] table[y index=0] {data.csv};
    \addplot[teal, ultra thick, dashed] coordinates {(3.3832, 0) (3.3832, 3)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[teal, mark=*] table [x expr=\coordindex+1, y index=0] {data.csv};
    \addplot[teal, ultra thick, dashed] coordinates {(1, \manmean) (10, \manmean)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, two issues remain:

- the mean needs to be calculated manually
- the line's start and end need to be entered manually

Really, the line should stretch along the full extend of the axis and touch the borders.

The pgfplots manual mentions `/pgfplots/xmin`, `/pgfplots/xmax`, `/pgfplots/ymin` and `/pgfplots/ymax` under *4.14.1 Configuration of Limits Ranges*. There is also `/pgfplots/boxplot/average` in *5.11 Statistics*. However, I cannot find a way to access these values.

Theoretically, I could calculate the mean using *awk*. This does not work, however, because *pdflatex* somehow will not compile with a shell command that uses `printf` and quotation marks.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
1.84919
0.97280
4.78586
3.95797
4.50753
2.52274
5.13984
0.29474
5.39946
4.40204
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[teal, mark=*] table [x expr=\coordindex+1, y index=0] {data.csv};
    \addplot[teal, ultra thick, dashed, mark=*] shell {awk '{ sum += $1 } END { printf "%i %f\n%i %f\n", 1, sum/NR, NR, sum/NR }' data.csv};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that the argument `-shell-escape` is required to compile a document that contains shell scripts, e.g. `pdflatex -shell-escape mwe-mean-awk.tex`.

The error it gives:

```
Runaway argument?
{awk '{ sum += $1 } END { printf "\end {axis} \end {tikzpicture} \end \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \pgfplots@addplotimpl@shell@opt was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.25 

?
```

Even if this did work, the line would still be too short for a pretty picture.

Comment: Pertaining the *awk* script, I just asked myself if the `%` and/or `\\` need to be escaped.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=100cm,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
level
1.84919
0.97280
4.78586
3.95797
4.50753
2.52274
5.13984
0.29474
5.39946
4.40204
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{dataA.csv}
level
2
4
6
8
10
9
7
5
3
1
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand\DrawVMean[1][]{
\draw[#1] 
  (axis cs:\Mean,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- 
  (axis cs:\Mean,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
}
\newcommand\DrawHMean[1][]{
\draw[#1] 
  (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},\Mean) -- 
  (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},\Mean);
}

\newcommand\GetMean[2]{
  \pgfplotstableread{#1}\tableA
  \pgfplotstableset{
    create on use/new/.style={
    create col/expr={\pgfmathaccuma + \thisrow{#2}}},
  }
  \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\tableA}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\NumRows}{\pgfplotsretval}
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{\numexpr\NumRows-1\relax}{new}\of{#1} 
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\Sum}{\pgfplotsretval}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\Mean}{\Sum/\NumRows}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\GetMean{data.csv}{level}
\begin{axis}
    \addplot[hist={bins=6,}, fill=teal, draw=teal!50!black] table[y index=0] {data.csv};
\DrawVMean[teal, ultra thick, dashed] 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\qquad
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\GetMean{data.csv}{level}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[teal, mark=*] table [x expr=\coordindex+1, y index=0] {data.csv};
\DrawHMean[teal, ultra thick, dashed] 
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\par\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
\GetMean{dataA.csv}{level}
\begin{axis}
    \addplot[hist={bins=6,}, fill=cyan!20, draw=cyan!50!black] table[y index=0] {dataA.csv};
\DrawVMean[orange, ultra thick, dashed] 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\qquad
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\GetMean{dataA.csv}{level}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[cyan!50, mark=*] table [x expr=\coordindex+1, y index=0] {dataA.csv};
\DrawHMean[orange, ultra thick, dashed] 
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

## Explanation

- Use `\GetMean{<data-file>}{<col-name>}` to get the mean for the column with name `<col-name>` in the file `<data-file>`.
- Inside the `axis` environment use `\DrawVMean[<options>]`/`\DrawHMean[<options>]` to automatically draw the vertical/horizontal line at the media position.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this useful code! However, it doesn't work well in combination with the dateplot library, see [question 376088](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376088) for a solution to this problem.