# pgfplot with date and automatically calculated mean

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable, dateplot

I have a pgfplot with dates for x and some values for y, for which I now want to add a mean line like it is done [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/268942/93970). The function `\DrawHMean` presented there however seems to have a problem with dates, I suspect `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}` and `…xmax}`. Unfortunately, a simple `\addplot expression {y=\Mean}` doesn't work as well. What can I do to get the (already calculated!) mean into the graph?

### MWE

The commented line responsible for drawing the mean line yields date related errors when activated.

```
\documentclass[varwidth=100cm,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
value date
1.84919 2017-04-09
0.97280 2017-04-10
4.78586 2017-04-11
3.95797 2017-04-12
4.50753 2017-04-13
2.52274 2017-04-14
5.13984 2017-04-15
0.29474 2017-04-16
5.39946 2017-04-17
4.40204 2017-04-18
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand\DrawHMean[1][]{
\draw[#1]
  (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},\Mean) --
  (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},\Mean);
}

\newcommand\GetMean[2]{
  \pgfplotstableread{#1}\tableA
  \pgfplotstableset{
create on use/new/.style={
create col/expr={\pgfmathaccuma + \thisrow{#2}}},
  }
  \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\tableA}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\NumRows}{\pgfplotsretval}
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{\numexpr\NumRows-1\relax}{new}\of{#1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\Sum}{\pgfplotsretval}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\Mean}{\Sum/\NumRows}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \GetMean{data.csv}{value}
  \begin{axis}[%
    date coordinates in=x,%
    xticklabel style={rotate=90,anchor=near xticklabel},%
    xticklabel=\day.\month.\year,%
  ]
    \addplot[red] table [x=date, y=value] {data.csv};
%     \DrawHMean[blue, ultra thick, dashed]
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8iT4.jpg]

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can search the first date given in the table

```
\newcommand\FirstDate{}
\newcommand\GetFirstDate[2]{%
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{#2}\of{#1}%
  \edef\FirstDate{\pgfplotsretval}%
}
```

and use it in

```
\newcommand\DrawHMean[2][]{%
  \draw[#1]
    ({axis cs:\FirstDate,\Mean}-|current axis.west) -- 
    ({axis cs:\FirstDate,\Mean}-|current axis.east);%
}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=100cm,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
value date
1.84919 2017-04-09
0.97280 2017-04-10
4.78586 2017-04-11
3.95797 2017-04-12
4.50753 2017-04-13
2.52274 2017-04-14
5.13984 2017-04-15
0.29474 2017-04-16
5.39946 2017-04-17
4.40204 2017-04-18
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand\DrawHMean[2][]{%
  \draw[#1]
    ({axis cs:\FirstDate,\Mean}-|current axis.west) -- 
    ({axis cs:\FirstDate,\Mean}-|current axis.east);%
}
\newcommand\FirstDate{}
\newcommand\GetFirstDate[2]{%
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{#2}\of{#1}%
  \edef\FirstDate{\pgfplotsretval}%
}
\newcommand\GetMean[2]{
  \pgfplotstableread{#1}\tableA
  \pgfplotstableset{
    create on use/new/.style={
    create col/expr={\pgfmathaccuma + \thisrow{#2}}},
  }
  \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\tableA}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\NumRows}{\pgfplotsretval}
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{\numexpr\NumRows-1\relax}{new}\of{#1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\Sum}{\pgfplotsretval}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\Mean}{\Sum/\NumRows}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \GetFirstDate{data.csv}{date}
  \GetMean{data.csv}{value}
  \begin{axis}[clip=false,%
    date coordinates in=x,%
    xticklabel style={rotate=90,anchor=near xticklabel},%
    xticklabel=\day.\month.\year,%
  ]
    \addplot[red] table [x=date, y=value] {data.csv};

     \DrawHMean[blue, ultra thick, dashed]{data.csv}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across a simpler solution using an internal function, in the axis options I added:

```
extra y ticks=\Mean,
extra y tick style={thick,blue,grid=major,grid style={thick,blue,dashed}},
extra y tick label={mean = $\pgfmathprintnumber\tick$},
```

This sets `\Mean` (which of course still needs to be calculated by `\GetMean` before) as an extra tick on the y axis. The whole example looks as follows:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=100cm,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
value date
1.84919 2017-04-09
0.97280 2017-04-10
4.78586 2017-04-11
3.95797 2017-04-12
4.50753 2017-04-13
2.52274 2017-04-14
5.13984 2017-04-15
0.29474 2017-04-16
5.39946 2017-04-17
4.40204 2017-04-18
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand\GetMean[2]{
  \pgfplotstableread{#1}\tableA
  \pgfplotstableset{
create on use/new/.style={
create col/expr={\pgfmathaccuma + \thisrow{#2}}},
  }
  \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\tableA}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\NumRows}{\pgfplotsretval}
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{\numexpr\NumRows-1\relax}{new}\of{#1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\Sum}{\pgfplotsretval}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\Mean}{\Sum/\NumRows}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \GetMean{data.csv}{value}
  \begin{axis}[%
date coordinates in=x,%
xticklabel style={rotate=90,anchor=near xticklabel},%
xticklabel=\day.\month.\year,%
extra y ticks=\Mean,
extra y tick style={thick,blue,grid=major,grid style={thick,blue,dashed}},% style options
extra y tick label={mean = $\pgfmathprintnumber\tick$},% label text, change to {} for empty label
  ]
\addplot[red] table [x=date, y=value] {data.csv};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

I leave esdd's answer as the accepted one since it answers my exact question, however this approach in my opinion serves better as a solution to the overall problem how to add a automatically calculated mean line to a pgfplot.